# how to design a zero address machine

Tags: stack, cpu-architecture

Anyone got any examples of a zero address stack based one? I've been looking for examples of a zero-address microprocessor so I can get my head around it, but I can't seem to find any. Any help on explaining on how to design one would be appreciated.

Comment: sorry for my ignorance.. a What?

Answer (score 2):

> 0-operand (zero address machines), so called stack machines: All arithmetic operations take place using the top one or two positions on the stack; 1-operand push and pop instructions are used to access memory:
>
> push a
>   push b
>   add
>   pop c

Just looking to see what a design of one looks like, so far everyone I've seen has had an MAR which, if I'm not wrong, is a memory address register.

So wouldn't that mean they aren't zero address machines?

Answer (score 1):

Today, you might get a better grasp of the concepts by looking and actually experimenting with common virtual machines. For instance the JVM is a stack-based machine and with the available tools for bytecode compilation and manipulation easy to experiment with.

Smalltalk is another example, but stack-based languages in general are worth a look, and the understanding gained there is easily transferable to the hardware level when needed.

Comment: c-Python is an other example.